# Can I have single String with different types of datas?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 types of data,for ex:- I need a single array of students with girls and boys names and also I need to retrieve girls and boys names separately.

can I do this in java with any descriptors?

Comment: use hashmap with two keys boys and girls.

Comment: programming languages can not identified a name separately it is girl name or boy name.you need a logic to do that

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> students = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
List<Student> boysList = new ArrayList<Student>();
...
List<Student> girlsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
...
students.put("girls", girlsList);
students.put("boys", boysList);
```

As is, you can't just throw random names in a string and expect the language to *know* which is which. If you are after a string representation of the two lists though, you could use something like the above and then use something like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to produce XML out of the given data structure.

EDIT:

To retrieve the details about the boys, you can do this:

```
for(Student boy : students.get("boys"))
{
    System.out.println(boy.getName());
}
```

For girls:

```
for(Student girl: students.get("girls"))
{
    System.out.println(boy.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the way

1. Create Class for Student.
2. Create List of Students or Seperate Lists

   ```
   class Student {
   private String name;
   private Gender gender;

   public Student(String name, Gender gender) {

       this.setName(name);
       this.setGender(gender);
   }

   public Gender getGender() {
       return gender;
   }

   public void setGender(Gender gender) {
       this.gender = gender;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

   // Provide method like get student etc. It is not efficient to put both
   // in one list you can use separate list as well or a Hashmap
    }
   public enum Gender {
       BOY, GIRL
   }
   ```